# Almost division ring but only one-side distributive

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

I am looking for an example of an algebraic structure that is almost a division ring, but is only left-distributive and not right-distributive.
Gérard Lang

Comment: What you are looking for are near-fields, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-field_(mathematics).

Comment: Thank you very much.